# Model Post and Topic through DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, model, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Heres the relation I'm trying to model in DynamoDB:
My service contains posts and topics. A post may belong to multiple topics. A topic may have multiple posts. All posts have an interest value which would be adjusted based on a combination of likes and time since posted, interest measures the popularity of a post at the current moment. If a post gets too old, its interest value will be 0 and stay that way forever (archival).

The REST api end points work like this:

- GET /posts/{id} returns a post-object containing title, text,   author name and a link to the authors rest endpoint (doesn't matter for this example) and the number of likes (the interest value is not included)
- GET /topics/{name} should return an object with both a list with the N newest posts of the topics as well as one for the N currently most interesting posts
- POST /posts/ creates a new post where multiple topics can be specified
- POST /topics/
  creates a new topic
- POST /likes/ creates a like for a specified post (does not actually create an object, just adds the user to the given post-object's list of likers, which is invisible to the users)

The problem now becomes, how do I create a relationship between topics and and posts in DynamoDB NoSql?

I thought about adding a list of copies of posts to tag entries in DynamboDB, where every tag has a list of both the newest and the most interesting Posts.
One way I could do this is by creating a cloudwatch job that would run every 10 minutes and loop through every topic object, finding both the most interesting and newest entries and then replacing the old lists of the topic.
Another job would also have to regularly update the "interest" value of every non archived post (keep in mind both likes and time have an effect on the interest value).

One problem with this is that a lot of posts in the Tag list would be out of date for 10 minutes in case the User makes a change or deletes the post. Likes will also not be properly tracked on the Tags post list. This could perhaps be solved with transactions, although dynamoDB is limited to 10 objects per transaction.
Another problem is that it would require the add-posts-to-tags job to load all the non archived posts into memory in order to manually sort them by both time and interest, split them up by tag and then adding the first N of both sets to the tag lists every 10 minutes.

---

I also had a another idea, by limiting the tags of a post that are allowed to 1, I could add the tag as a partition key, with the post-time as the sort key, and use a GSI to add Interest as a second sort key.
This does have several downsides though:

- very popular tags may be limited to a single parition since all the posts share a single partition key
- Tag limit is 1
- A cloudwatch job to adjust the Interest value of posts may still be required
- It would require use of a GSI which may lead to dangerous race conditions

But it would have the advantage that there are no replications of the post objects aside from the GSI. It would also allow basically infinite paging of all posts by date instead of being limited to just the N newest posts.

So what is a good approach here? It seams both of my solutions have horrible dealbreakers. Is this just one of those problems that NoSQL simply can't solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to model relational data using a non relational DB ,
to do this I would use 2 types of DB ,
I would store in dynamo the post information
in your example it would be  :

```
GET /posts/{id} 
POST /posts/
POST /likes/creates
```

For the topic related information I would use Elastic search ([Amazon Elasticsearch Service](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/))

`GET /topics/{name}` : the search index would stored the full topic info as well  post id's that , and the relevant fields you want to search for (in your case update date to get the most recent posts)

what this will entail is background process (in dynamoDB this can be done via [streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html)) that takes changes to the dynamoDB for new post's , update to like count etc.. and populates the search index.

Note: this can also be solved using graphDB but for scaling purposes better separate the source of the data (post's ) and the data relations (topic).

Comment: thanks, I'll look into elastic search. Do you think it may also handle adjusting the interest value?

Comment: Yes if you add the amounts of like's each post received into the elastic index , you can query based on it

Comment: yeah but time (and maybe even other factors) is also gonna play a role. so it would need to be continually updated until the post is quarantined. But I think I'll probably figure it out as I go